# How do I replace a Bryant Furnace 397HAW pilot assembly P671-1403?

Tags: hvac

I have a 397HAW Bryant furnace that needs a new pilot assembly P671-1403.
Does anyone have any instruction steps how to go about it?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Could you share a few photos of your furnace and pilot assembly? Several of us could look at the furnace and give suggestions as to steps and order, but we don't know the last 40 years of Bryant appliances well enough to compose it from memory. Below your post click the Edit button, then the mountains-and-sun icon in the editor to attach a photo.

Comment: Have you searched the internet for the instruction manual?